# SQL. Вывести несгруппированные дубликаты

Tags: база-данных, sql, sql-server, mysql

Добрый день,

т.к. SQL не моя сфера, сооброжаловки не хватает написать простой, как мне кажется, запрос.Итак есть sqlite3 и в нем 1 таблица

```
id - primary keymd5 - varcharpath - varcharhostname - varchar
```

Хочу вывести все поля с одинаковым md5 (все остальное разное). Найти такие строки ума хватило

```
select *, count(md5) from lastbl GROUP BY md5  HAVING count(md5) >= 2;
```

Но в таком случае я получаю свои дубли сгруппированными, т.е.

```
851036|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\file4|PG02|7372946|000126150751dc2425acebb8c3e629d4|\var\spool\file1|G8|2744074|0001468a9f8224d2812b871aff26cdbb|\etc\qwerty\baspro\30364_1.txt|INTER02|5
```

последний столбец - кол-во повторений такого md5

А мне бы вывести именно список дубликатов, без группировки.. Что-то типа такого (но having без group нельзя, отсюда у меня пауза:) )

```
select *, count(md5) from lastbl HAVING count(md5) >= 2;
```

результат в виде перечисления только дубликатов md5

```
851036|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\file4|PG01811036|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\file4|PG02251036|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\file4|PG0985130|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\copy\file4|PG02111036|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\zapas\file4|PG0225136|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\directory_\refile4|PG025236|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\filedd|PG02841036|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\fileasd4|PG032661|0000c7b8aadcba1e1fbe5c94e97d3787|\var\fildfdse4\readme.txt|G02
```

Comment: Покажите табличку, которую вы в итоге хотите получить.---------------@Anton Shevtsov, Это вопрос на форум [ХэшКод](http://hashcode.ru/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну вот и ответ

```
select * from lastbl where md5 in (select md5 from lastbl GROUP BY md5  HAVING count(md5) > 1);
```

Comment: Иногда проще распарсить вывод в баше, иногда, т.е запустить mysql c -e , а вывод уже sort и uniq, например.

Comment: @pyatak у меня наоборот.. долго парсилось и собиралось в баше, затем когда файл получился красивый и правильный, залил его в sqlite, чтобы средствами sql навести окончательную красоту. Быстрее вышло. Строк в БД около 1млн.

Comment: Ну тогда, добавить нечего, все как положено.